# Calculate number of days between two variable (one a set variable, the other from fact)

Tags: ansible, yaml, jinja2

I've been looking around like crazy to find a solution to this but so far I've been unsuccessful : Calculate number of days between an inventory variable and an Ansible fact.

I have no issue when I manually set both variable, both are recognized as a date and I can work my may around from there like so : (this is the expected output)

Task working between 2 manually set variables:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost

  vars:
    prev_date: 2020-12-01
    cur_date: 2020-12-31

  tasks:
    - name: prev_date debug
      debug:
        msg:
          - "prev_date: {{ prev_date }}"
          - "prev_date type: {{ prev_date | type_debug }}"

    - name: cur_date debug
      debug:
        msg:
          - "cur_date: {{ cur_date }}"
          - "cur_date type: {{ cur_date | type_debug }}"

    # This is the output I want to get but I want cur_date from a dynamic source (fact or shell through register)
    - name: Calculate number of days between prev_date and cur_date (intended result)
      debug:
        msg: "Number of days = {{ (cur_date - prev_date).days }}"
```

Working output:

```
TASK [prev_date debug] *************************************************************************************************************************************************
Thursday 31 December 2020  12:55:28 +0100 (0:00:00.227)       0:00:00.227 *****
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "prev_date: 2020-12-01",
        "prev_date type: date"
    ]
}

TASK [cur_date debug] **************************************************************************************************************************************************
Thursday 31 December 2020  12:55:29 +0100 (0:00:00.249)       0:00:00.476 *****
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "cur_date: 2020-12-31",
        "cur_date type: date"
    ]
}

TASK [Calculate number of days between prev_date and cur_date (intended result)] ***************************************************************************************
Thursday 31 December 2020  12:55:29 +0100 (0:00:00.144)       0:00:00.621 *****
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Number of days = 30"
}
```

Now when I want to use ansible fact to get the current date dynamically on each run (`ansible_date_time.date`) because of the variables type

Sample of tasks to reproduce the error

```yaml
    - name: Value and type of ansible_date_time.date
      debug:
        msg:
          - "ansible_date_time.date: {{ ansible_date_time.date }}"
          - "ansible_date_time.date type: {{ ansible_date_time.date | type_debug }}"

    # Failing due to conditional not working with attribute not being date on ansible_date_time.date
    - name: Calculate number of days between ansible_date_time.date
      debug:
        msg:
          - "Number of days = {{ (ansible_date_time.date - prev_date).days }}"
```

I get the following output and error:

```
TASK [New source ansible fact date] ************************************************************************************************************************************
Thursday 31 December 2020  13:06:41 +0100 (0:00:00.143)       0:00:00.741 *****
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "ansible_date_time.date: 2020-12-31",
        "ansible_date_time.date type: AnsibleUnsafeText"
    ]
}

TASK [Calculate number of days between ansible_date_time.date] *********************************************************************************************************
Thursday 31 December 2020  13:06:41 +0100 (0:00:00.150)       0:00:00.892 *****
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on (Number of days = {{ (ansible_date_time.date - prev_date).days }}): unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'AnsibleUnsafeText' and 'datetime.date'"}
```

I tried find ways to create a new variable out of `ansible_date_time.date` but I was unable to convert it to `datetime.date` if that's even possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ansible_date_time.date` is a string, so you will have to convert it to a `date` or a `datetime`.

Surprisingly enough, Ansible does not have any means to convert a string to a `date` right away, but you can convert it to a `datetime` using the [`to_datetime` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#handling-dates-and-times).

Then, because `prev_date` contains a `date` and not a `datetime`, you can convert the `datetime` you just created to a `date` via the [`date()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.date) function of Python's `datetime`.

So the playbook would be:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_subset:
    - min
      
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: >-
          {{ 
            (
              (ansible_date_time.date | to_datetime('%Y-%m-%d')).date() 
              - prev_date
            ).days 
          }}
      vars:
        prev_date: 2020-12-01
```

Which will give:

```
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: '30'
```

Comment: Damned
I tried so many combination and spent so much time on this.
Yes, ansible is limited and doesn't provide a way to convert str to date, figured that out after some time. I did try to do that with to_datetime aswell but i missed ".date()" in my syntax this is the most elegant answer I was hoping for, thank you mate.

Comment: @Geoffrey if you find "out of the box" ansible limited for whatever requirement you have, it is pretty simple to create your own custom filter (or whatever other type of plugin) where you will get all the power of python at your fingertips. => https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_plugins.html

Answer (score 2):

The task below does the job

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "Number of days =
              {{ ((ansible_date_time.date|to_datetime('%Y-%m-%d') -
                  (prev_date ~ ' 00:00:00')|to_datetime)).days }}"
```

Comment: Looking at this I ended in a similar `prev_date|string|to_datetime`. From what I tested `(prev_date ~ ' 00:00:00')|to_datetime` is doing an implicit string conversion, which is backed up by the fact that your snippet also works doing `(prev_date ~ '')|to_datetime`