# How to convert UNIX epoch format %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S to UTC format, in example %Y-%m-%d with Ansible?

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx

I am trying to convert UNIX epoch formats to UTC readable for humans but it generates errors in many cases.

- convert UNIX epoch format `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S`, value `1514764800`
- to UTC format example `%Y-%m-%d`, value `2022-03-25`

I also need help calculating that in days with Ansible

If someone has had any request regarding what I mentioned it would help me.

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: true
  become: false

  vars:
    example_epoch_times: 1514764800

  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        _thirty_days_ago_epoch: "{{ (ansible_date_time['epoch']|int)-(86400*30) }}"

    - name: task one
      debug:
        msg: "{{'%Y-%m-%d' | strftime(item)}}"
              #msg: "{{ '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' | strftime(item) }} has been longer than 30 days"
      register: DIAS
      with_items: "{{ example_epoch_times }}"

    - name: hour
      debug:
        msg: "{{ DAYS.results[0].msg}}"
      register: TOTAL

    - name: test
      debug:
        msg: "{{ DAYS | json_query(machine) }}"
      vars:
        machine: 'results[0].msg'

    - name: Environment
      set_fact:
        vmid: "{{ DAYS | json_query(machine2) }}"
      vars:
        machine2: 'results[0].msg'

    - name: TIME DAYS
      debug:
        msg: "{{ ((ansible_date_time.date | to_datetime('%Y-%m-%d')).date() - TOTAL2 ).days }}"
      vars:
        TOTAL2: "{{ vmid }}"
```

```json
TASK [TIME DAYS] ************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ ((ansible_date_time.date | to_datetime('%Y-%m-%d')).date() - TOTAL2 ).days }}): unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.date' and 'AnsibleUnsafeText'"}

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=6    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

But if I don't declare the `TOTAL2` variable and insert the punctual date if it works

```yaml
 - name: TIME DAYS
  debug:
    msg: "{{ ((ansible_date_time.date | to_datetime('%Y-%m-%d')).date() - TOTAL2 ).days }}"
  vars:
    TOTAL2: "2017-12-31"
```

```json
TASK [TIME DAYS] ************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "1886"
}
```

help me ansible runner task thenks

Comment: Does [Calculate number of days between two variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65520845/) answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

is my playbook functional

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: true
  become: false
  vars:
  example_epoch_times: 1514764800
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        _thirty_days_ago_epoch: "{{ (ansible_date_time['epoch']|int)-(86400*30) }}"

    - name: Displaying Older Than 30 Days
      debug:
        msg: "{{'%Y-%m-%d' | strftime(item)}}"
      
      register: DAYS
      with_items: "{{ example_epoch_times }}"



    - name: Hours
      debug:
        var:  DAYS.results[0].msg
      register: TOTAL



    - name: Enviroment
      set_fact:
        vmid: "{{ DAYS | json_query(machine2) }}"
      vars:
        machine2: 'results[0].msg'
      register: clean


    - name: TIME DAYS
      debug:
        msg: "{{ (ansible_date_time.date | to_datetime('%Y-%m-%d')) - (DAYS.results[0].msg | to_datetime('%Y-%m-%d')) }}"
```